# iOS unrecognized selector sent to instance error

Tags: ios, swift, wechat

I add a button at the LoginViewController. 
Here is the code in LoginViewComtroller

```
loginButton?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(LoginViewController.wechatLogin), for: .touchDown)

func wechatLogin()  {
    sendWXAuthRequest()  
}

func sendWXAuthRequest() {
    print("hello")
    let req: SendAuthReq = SendAuthReq()
    req.scope = "snsapi_userinfo,snsapi_base"
    WXApi.send(req)
}

func onResp(_ resp: BaseResp!) {
    print(resp)
}
```

Here is code in AppDelegate.swift

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        //register
        buildKeyWindow()
        let right =  WXApi.registerApp("My_Appid")
        print(right)
        return true
    }


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, handleOpen url: URL) -> Bool {
        return WXApi.handleOpen(url, delegate: self)
    }


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
        return WXApi.handleOpen(url, delegate: self)
    }
```

When I first run the application, there is a error show when I get into WeChat. 
Then I second run the it, there is a some error which said "unrecognized selector sent to instance"

[image: The error description]

Comment: when I comment out the  WXApi.registerApp("My_Appid").  Everything is ok except the button is enable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change `-all_load` to `-force_load` in `Other Linker Flags` of your Buliding settings

Comment: Using Xcode 8.3 with WeChat iOS SDK 1.7.7 here, neither `-Obj-c` nor `-force_load` works, but `-all_load` fixed problem.

Comment: it's -all_load, not -all-load. I used to have -all-load and it didn't work.